# T-SQL Substring of a Link

Tags: t-sql

I have a string with which I want to retrieve a substring out of:

```
"app/reports/here"
```

The resulting substring I want is `"app/reports"`

I some T-SQL as below:

```
DECLARE @document varchar(64);  
SELECT @document = 'app/reports/here';  
SELECT substring(@document, 0, CHARINDEX('/', replace(@document,'app/','')));  
GO
```

The result of the code above is "app/rep".

How could I get the full string I need? Someone about the CHARINDEX is confusing me..

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to parse n Positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add 4 to the `CHARINDEX` since you replace 4 characters from the original string with an empty string so the result from `CHARINDEX` is shifted by that. So it should be:

```
DECLARE @document varchar(64);  
SELECT @document = 'app/reports/here';  
SELECT substring(@document, 0, CHARINDEX('/', replace(@document,'app/',''))+4);  
GO
```